# Use typing with GraphQL in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, graphql

In NextJS we have this bit of code that calls GraphQL.  However, it uses the "`" (tick mark").

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: gql`
        query Countries {
          countries {
            code
            name
            emoji
          }
        }
      `,
    });

    
    return {
      props: {
        countries: data.countries.slice(0, 4),
      },
   };
}
```

This part is sort of bothering me because it is untyped.

```
gql`
   query Countries {
      countries {
          code
          name
          emoji
      }
   }
`,
```

Is there a better way of doing this with TypeScript?

Comment: You need a library. graphql-code-generator does this by parsing queries in separate files and spewing out a ton a hooks based on your schema. Otherwise, not unless you want to lose sanity with a query builder of sorts. Link here: https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen

Comment: The stuff between the backticks is of type string. Types are defined in the schema on the server. You can reuse those types on the front end as well, see https://atheros.ai/blog/generate-javascript-static-types-from-graphql-typescript-and-flow